# ¿Cómo uso el '$' en un snippets en visual studio code?

Tags: php, visual-studio

Estoy intentando crear un snippet en de php en visual stydio code.
Quiero que ese snippet incluya ya una variable, pero cuando disparo el snippet me quita el simbolo de dolar de las variables:

codigo snippet:

```
    "Print to console": {
        "prefix": "rick",
        "body": [
            "$rick = $1;",
            "dump($rick);",
        ],
        "description": "hace un dump"
    }
```

codigo resultante de disparar el snippet:

```
rick = ;
dump(rick);
```

No me sierve usar '\' como caracter de escape:

```
"Print to console": {
        "prefix": "rick",
        "body": [
            "\$rick = $1;",
            "dump(\$rick);",
        ],
        "description": "hace un dump"
    }
```

me da el sigiente error:

```
Invalid escape character in string.json(261)
```

Comment: Trata de poner dos símbolos *dollar*: `$$` o tambien con doble slash: `\\$`

Comment: Perfecto @MarioGuiber el _doble dolar_ funciona.Aún soy nuevo aqui. ¿Cual es la ventaja de hacer un comentario en vez de una respuesta? ¿Como califico tu respuesta?

Comment: Si te ha servido mi comentario la pasaré como respuesta y podrás marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Otra cosa @MarioGuiber ,  seguro que donde pone eso hay mas información interesante ¿Me recomidas alguna documentación?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder escapar correctamente el símbolo `$` en el `snippet` te recomiendo dos opciones:

1. Poner doble `$$`:

   ```
   "Print to console": {
       "prefix": "rick",
       "body": [
           "$$rick = $$1;",
           "dump($$rick);",
       ],
       "description": "hace un dump"
   }
   ```
2. Poner doble slash `\\`:

   ```
   "Print to console": {
       "prefix": "rick",
       "body": [
           "\\$rick = \\$1;",
           "dump(\\$rick);",
       ],
       "description": "hace un dump"
   }
   ```

Respuesta basada en una pregunta de [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215705/escaping-the-character-in-snippets)